# Not able to send SMS even through the emulator and a real phone

Tags: android

I have written code to send a sms at a click of a Button which isn't doing it, and the error is:

> Sending SMS message: user 10037 doesnot have android.permission.SEND_SMS

Can anybody help me? I don't know where the problem is. My code is as:

[image]

[image]

and the XML is as:

[image]

I have even included the user permission in manifest file as SEND_SMS.

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.volienceagainstwomen.vaw"
android:versionCode="1"

android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.SEND_SMS"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />   

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.volienceagainstwomen.vaw.MainActivity_VAW"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.volienceagainstwomen.vaw.MainActivity_Settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity__settings" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.volienceagainstwomen.vaw.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and the logcat is as:

```
03-25 17:24:10.917: E/InputEventReceiver(698): Exception dispatching input event.
03-25 17:24:10.986: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698): java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: User 10044 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:413)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:87)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at com.volienceagainstwomen.vaw.MainActivity_VAW.sendSms(MainActivity_VAW.java:114)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at com.volienceagainstwomen.vaw.MainActivity_VAW$2.onTouch(MainActivity_VAW.java:98)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7122)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
03-25 17:24:11.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(698):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
```

Comment: If you find a way to achieve it please tell us.

Comment: You should post at least your Manifest and your LogCat. Then we'll ask you what else to post.

Answer (score 2):

An emulator can't call nor send SMS, since it doesn't have a SIM Card, which is needed to place calls or send SMS.

These are services which have a cost which is then charged to your SIM.
You can't have these services FOR FREE!

It would be beautiful, if we could send SMS or MMS via the emulator...

Comment: i know i cant send sms through an emulator .....but wen i run this apk through my phone...the app just closes and the sms is not sent...

Comment: So, probably there's some error in the initialization of your app, not in the SMS part. You should post at least your Manifest and your LogCat. Then we'll ask you what else to post.